# Unable to connect to internet on RHEL-7 after botched upgrade

Tags: networking, rhel, troubleshooting

So my situation is, I was previously able to setup network connectivity on my RHEL-7 guest OS (running on host OS Windows 7 using VirtualBox). I messed up an upgrade causing a kernel panic, so I reverted to my current kernel, but now it seems I have lost my network connectivity. Removing the new kernel did not help. Every now and then I would get the balloon message that says "Activation of network connection failed."

Not sure what information I should provide, so I refer to [RHEL 7.0 can't connect to internet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141175/rhel-7-0-cant-connect-to-internet):

My `ifconfig enp0s3` output:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::90e9:5511:7bf5:25da  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 78:2b:cb:b6:6f:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 42574  bytes 8944263 (8.5 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1284  bytes 283643 (276.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My `ip ro` output:

```
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

Contents of my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s3
UUID=d95e90e6-12c4-49c5-8df1-4bb5c70c6b69
DEVICE=enp0s3
ONBOOT=yes
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more info, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided I can tell that your network connection is "UP", configured to use DHCP, and set to automatically connect.  RHEL7 uses NetworkManager by default.  It would help if you could also share the output of this command:

```
$ nmcli connection show
```

You may have a connection defined, but not set to automatically connect.  If the previous command shows any connections with the "enp0s3" keyword, you could try to manually activate it like this:

```
$ nmcli connection up "System enp0s3"
or
$ nmcli connection up "enp0s3"
```

If that doesn't work you could consider looking at the logs while the networking is re-started like this:

```
$ journalctl -flu NetworkManager &
$ systemctl restart NetworkManager
```